# local variable 'content_type' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, forms, function, post

I have a problem with function post in my `views.py`. The problem is when I send a POST form.

```
UnboundLocalError at /pl/
local variable 'content_type' referenced before assignment
```

I installed new app for rating new contents and I need to add some code in my `views.py` to the function `def post`. Now it works only for `CommentForm` (Comments).

**views.py**:

```
class IndexView(AllAdsViewMixin, ListView):
    model = UserContent
    template_name = 'user_content/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'object'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last all five published contents"""
        return UserContent.objects.filter(state='1').order_by('-published')[:5]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        comment_initial_data = {
            'content_type': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model).id
        }

        reply_initial_data = {
            'content_type': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Comment).id
        }

        comment_form = CommentForm(initial=comment_initial_data)
        reply_form = CommentForm(initial=reply_initial_data)
        mainpage_images = MainPageImages.objects.first()
        rate_form = RateForm()
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = comment_form
        context['reply_form'] = reply_form
        context['mainpage_images'] = mainpage_images
        context['rate_form'] = rate_form

        return context

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            content_type_id = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
            object_id_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
            content_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')

            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(content_type_id)
            print(object_id_data)
            print(content_data)

        else:
            print(comment_form.errors)

        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user,
            content_type=content_type,
            object_id=object_id_data,
            content=content_data,
        )

        return self.get(request, **kwargs)
```

As you can see guys I need edit this function for add `RateForm`, because now it's only for `CommentForm`. Can someone help me?

Comment: you don't set the `content_type` variable if your form is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only set `content_type` when your form is valid:

```
if comment_form.is_valid():
    # ...
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(content_type_id)
    # ...
else:
    print(comment_form.errors)
```

So when `comment_form.is_valid()` is *false*, the variable is never set. You  have the same issue with `object_id_data` and `content_data`.

Perhaps you need to re-think what should be returned when the form is not correct? It seems to me that the `Comment.objects.get_or_create()` call should only be exected when your form is valid:

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

    if comment_form.is_valid():
        content_type_id = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
        object_id_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(content_type_id)
        print(object_id_data)
        print(content_data)

        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user,
            content_type=content_type,
            object_id=object_id_data,
            content=content_data,
        )

    else:
        print(comment_form.errors)


    return self.get(request, **kwargs)
```

Now it doesn't matter that those variables are not set outside the `if` block, they are simply not needed elsewhere.

Comment: Also `object_id_data` and `content_data`.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you. But how can I add my RateForm to this function?

Comment: @Dinson: please keep your posts to *one issue at a time*. Your `RateForm` is a separate issue that should be in a separate post, and moreover you haven't told us nearly enough about how that form should work for users. Are both forms submitted together, or only one or the other? What should happen when it is submitted, etc.? Write this up in a new post, comments are not the place to diagnose issues.

Comment: Sorry. Everything I wrote too chaotically. I will try to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Because you define `content_type` within the `if comment_form.is_valid():` statement.

If you don't go within this if statement, `content_type` variable is never setted, but used further.

You could do something like `content_type = None` **before** the if statement, so your variable exists anyway.
Obviously `None` may not be the right default value for this var, but it's up to you.